# Mounting a virtual drive (vhd) in a windows azure instance of web/worker role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles, vhd

In old versions of windows azure sdk we could use `ClouDrive` class to mount a virtual disk. Not anymore, there is no such a class in the new sdks (2.x)

my cloud project contains:

- a worker role.
- a vhd file stored as a page blob.

**Question:**
How can i get the vhd file mounted as a virtual drive inside of the worker role instance ?

Thank you.

P.S. : Im using windows azure sdk 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the 1.7 version of the storage client library.  It is shipped in the latest SDK in the ref folder as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive.dll and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll.  Just add the DLLs to your project and you can continue using the CloudDrive class.

However, note that CloudDrive never made it out of beta and is now discontinued.  You should begin migrating your application to use the new Azure Files - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx.

Comment: Exactly what i need to know

Comment: Directory for Azure SDK 2.3 is: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.3\ref`